# Is there a python code to shift and total/count data from a column in a dataframe

Tags: python, data-science, feature-extraction, feature-engineering

The original table looks like this:

```
| s/n  | i.d |  T1  |
|------|-----|------|
|  0   |  A  |   2  |
|  1   |  B  |   2  |
|  2   |  C  |   0  |
|  3   |  A  |   2  |
|  4   |  B  |   0  | 
|  5   |  C  |   2  | 
|  6   |  A  |   1  |
|  7   |  B  |   0  |
|  8   |  C  |   1  |
```

and the final table like this:

```
| s/n  | i.d |  T1  |prev_total_T1 | prev_no_of_T1_2  |
|------|-----|------|--------------|------------------|
|  0   |  A  |   2  |      0       |        0         |   
|  1   |  B  |   2  |      0       |        0         |     
|  2   |  C  |   0  |      0       |        0         |    
|  3   |  A  |   2  |      2       |        1         |    
|  4   |  B  |   0  |      2       |        1         |    
|  5   |  C  |   2  |      0       |        0         |     
|  6   |  A  |   1  |      4       |        2         |    
|  7   |  B  |   0  |      2       |        1         |     
|  8   |  C  |   1  |      2       |        1         |
```

prev_total_T1 == (shift and total the previous record and update)
simply an addition of the total previous T1 number for the individual i.d.
i.e, for the first instance, i.d A,B,C has no previous T1 data so they are 0,0,0 respectively
the second instance, i.d A,B,C had 2,2,0 respectively
the third instance, i.d A,B,C had 2,0,2 and 2,2,0 data respectively and so we add them to give 4,2,2 respectively

prev_no_of_T1_2 == (shift and count the previous record and update)
i.e an increment of 1 for every previous number of times the number '2' appeared in T1 column
for the first instance, there was no previous record in A,B,C so we write 0,0,0 respectively
for the second instance the number '2' appeared previously in i.d A and B and not in i.d C so we write 1,1,0 respectively
for the third instance the number '2' appeared previously in i.d A and C but not in B and so it produces 1,0,1(i.d A,B,C respectively) but we add this with the previous individual result 1,1,0 + 1,0,1 and we have 2,1,1 for i.d A,B,C respectively and so on

Answer (score 0):

You need to group the data with `i.d` column and perform shift using `shift` function and group the shifted data with `i.d` again and use `cumsum` to get `prev_no_of_T1`. For `prev_no_of_T1_2` just divide `prev_no_of_T1` by 2.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('test2.csv')
#shift the data groupwise
df['shifted'] = df.groupby('i.d')['T1'].shift(1).fillna(0)
# take grouwise cumulative sum
df['prev_total_T1'] = df.groupby('i.d')['shifted'].cumsum().fillna(0)
# divide the  prev_total_T1 with 2
df['prev_no_of_T1_2'] = df['prev_total_T1']/2
```

| s/n | i.d | T1 | shifted | prev_total_T1 | prev_no_of_T1_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | B | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | C | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | A | 2 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | B | 0 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 5 | C | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 6 | A | 1 | 2 | 4 | 2 |
| 7 | B | 0 | 0 | 2 | 1 |
| 8 | C | 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 |